# PHP's CarbonPeriod put all data from the interval into one array

Tags: php, php-carbon

So I have this code to get the data from the database:

```
// get custom holidays
$companyHolidays = Holiday::query()->get();
```

now to get this output I did `dd($companyHolidays->toArray());`
[image]

these start and end dates need to be put into a DateInterval using Carbon.

So I did this:

```
$parsedCompanyHolidays = CarbonPeriod::create($companyHolidays[0]->start, $companyHolidays[0]->end);
```

this outputs, using                     `dd($parsedCompanyHolidays->toArray())`;

[image]

the issue now is that it only shows the first `Osterferien` but not the other ones from the database? What are ways to get all of them into one array?

Because later I would need to `continue` a generation of dates that are inside these dates

```
                   while ($i < $eventRepeats) {

                        // add one week
                        $eventStart->addDays(7);


                        if (in_array($eventStart->translatedFormat('Y-m-d'), $holidaysArray)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        // todo: not grabbing the holidays correctly
//                        if (in_array($eventStart->translatedFormat('Y-m-d'), $parsedCompanyHolidays)) {
//                            continue;
//                        }


                        echo '<div class="text-primary font-normal mt-6 mb-2">'.$count++.'. Termin</div>';
                        echo '<div class="bg-gray rounded-lg border-l-4">';
                        echo '<div class="p-3">';
                        echo $eventStart->translatedFormat('l, d. F Y, H:i');
                        echo ' - ';
                        echo $eventEnd->translatedFormat('H:i');
                        echo '</div></div>';

                        // increase iteration
                        $i++;

                    }
```

:

Comment: `$companyHolidays[0]` would only get the first result in the array, which is `Osterferien`

Comment: @aynber that does make sense, I would probably need a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, and you'll need to merge the resulting arrays if you want it all in one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$companyHolidays = Holiday::all();
$newholiday = [];
foreach($companyHolidays as $holiday){
  $newholiday[] = [
     'id' => $holiday->id,
     'title' => $holiday->title,
     'start' => $holiday->start,
     'end' => $holiday->end,
     'parsed_company_holidays'=> CarbonPeriod::create($holiday->start, $holiday->end);
        ];
    }
```